# How to close the pop up window in selenium running?

Tags: selenium, popupwindow

I wanna close the pop up window (known window name), and back to the original window. 
What shall I do?
If I can't get a constant of the close button in window. so is there any general behavior to reach the goal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
selenium.Close();
selenium.SelectWindow("null");
```

Answer (score 9):

Using WebDriver (shown with Java) you could do something like this:

```
// instantiate your driver
...

// get window handle
String baseWindowHdl = driver.getWindowHandle();

// navigate to pop-up
...

// close pop-up
driver.close();

// switch back to base window
driver.switchTo().window(baseWindowHdl);
```

Comment: //navigate to pop-up
Here, isn't necessary to switch to defaultContent as follow?:
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

Comment: You're right - it would probably work as well. My example was more about to show the closing details.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you are still looking for an answer, but i had some troubles with this.
After spending more than one hour on searching for a way to do it, dont want to use webdriver. I tried using the garbage collector:

```
Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium(......);
selenium.start();

................

selenium.close(); //to terminate testing window
selenium = null;  //make sure there are no references to the file
System.gc();      //now the garbage collector can kick in
```

This worked for me.