# How to close the pop up window using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I tried closing the pop up using ESC key

```
new Actions(this.driver).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ESCAPE)).perform();
```

and

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.delay(1000);

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.delay(1000);
```

It didn't work . Could some one help?

Comment: Here is solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720180/how-to-close-the-pop-up-window-in-selenium-running

Comment: Tried this.. didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Your over complicating it, all you need to do is call Selenium's `WebDriver.close()` method. Lint to API [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#close%28%29)